# timeout when reading excel file inside AWS S3 from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import boto3

aws_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
aws_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=aws_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)
response = s3.get_object(Bucket='testesolaire', Key='globalterrorismdb_0522dist.xlsx')
data  = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

But I am getting `Task timed out after 62.06 seconds` in the following line:

```
data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-01-08T08:24:17.460Z ebe0a951-8656-4736-8871-0b325ac17f63 Task timed out after 62.06 seconds"
}
```

I already tried to change the timeout option in lambda function option *General configuration > Timeout* to 15min, but no success.

Does someone knows what can be the problem?

Comment: Is your lambda in a VPC and does it have proper routing to S3? Why is your logic outside of the handler function?

Comment: Lambda doesn't have a VPC. I will check the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. The memory wasn't enough. My excel file has around 100mb and the default lambda memory is 128mb. I have changed to 3006MB and set the timeout to 15min and it worked. Actually, in the first time when I changed the timeout to 15min it already worked, but I should realize that the erro had change from "timeout" to "Runtime exited with error: signal: killed" (low memory).